# Trigonometric solution for $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sin^n (x) \cos^m (x) dx $?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

At home I came across the exercise and had to compute: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^n (x) \cos^m (x) dx $ with $m$, $n \in \mathbb{N} $

My current set of tools for solving problems of that kind is rather limited: This problem can be easily done via integration by parts.

However I wonder, if one could also come up with a solution just relying on a few common known trig identities for:

$\sin, \cos$ are orthogonal and thus: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin (x) \cos (x) dx  = 0 $

$\sin(x) = \cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$

double angular formular,.. just to state a few. In fact wikis contain quite a lot.

In fact I would like to solve this problem without the integration by parts methods or relying on the big guns. I prefer reducing a problem to something I already know and try to see, if my other tools can still be used.

I am afraid so, that one cannot circumvent using general power reduction formula or the general multiple angle formula..

Thus I would be very happy about any constructive hint, comment or answer.

Comment: Why are you bothered by or afraid of using integration by parts? This is *exactly* the kind of problem it is meant for. You write about not wanting to pull out "the big guns," but integration by parts is hardly a "big gun." It is a very basic technique. The way to appreciate concepts is to use them in settings where they are really helpful.

Comment: @KCd, I think solving a problem with a tool or knowing that a certain tool will solve a problem is just a beginning for me. I know how to solve this and similar problems in particular. I believe there is a solution functioning without integration by parts, just using trigonometric identities. However it seems I can't do that, which makes me believe, I just don't yet know enough about trig identities or other methods to solve it. Doing the same things over and over again is boring and don't give you really much insight in things. This is my belief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ in terms of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$, the apply the binomial theorem and the fact that for every $m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ we have $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{mix}\,dx = 0$.